# Does destroying GtkBuilder destroy all created widgets?

Tags: gtk

Question regarding GtkBuilder.
When we unref builder pointer does it destroys all the screens/widgets the builder had created?

```
if( builder_ptr )
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder_ptr));
```

Suppose we have created one screen using Glade/XML with some 2-3 top_level windows in it

```
gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder_ptr, "Test.glade", &error )
```

and generated GtkBuilder pointer (as above) so after deleting this pointer does it deletes created Windows or do we need to manually delete these windows?

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkBuilder.html#GtkBuilder.description):

> A GtkBuilder holds a reference to all
>   objects that it has constructed and
>   drops these references when it is
>   finalized. This finalization can cause
>   the destruction of non-widget objects
>   or widgets which are not contained in
>   a toplevel window. For toplevel
>   windows constructed by a builder, it
>   is the responsibility of the user to
>   call gtk_widget_destroy() to get rid
>   of them and all the widgets they
>   contain.

So, no, GtkBuilder does not do this for you, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, so i have to call `gtk_widget_destroy()` on every top level window constructed by builder that's what you are saying?

Comment: @PP: Yes, that is what the documentation is saying.